# difference between a function with and without parenthesis in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have two questions concerning python assuming the code below:

1. Why it is not possible to pass a function with parentheses or parameters to *add_command*?
2. What shall I do if my CreateWindow function has to take parameters?

Here's the line of code:

```
filemenu.add_command(label="update...", command=CreateWindow)
```

Comment: What parameters do you want to pass to add windows?

Comment: the fields that the windows must have as a start

Comment: should this be marked as a duplicate? At it's core, this question is just a rephrasing of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5767228/7432

Comment: I decided not to vote 'close' because, while the answer is a (succinct) duplicate, the question is not, and this one is well phrased in a way that could show up in a search.  It is not obvious that ` Nothing happening when I click a Button in tkinter` is about functions versus function calls.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Doing `command=CreateWindow(some_argument)` will cause CreateWindow to be executed immediately, and whatever it returns will be used as the parameter for `command`. Python isn't smart enough to guess that you want CreateWindow to be the callback and not its return value.
2. Use a lambda expression: `filemenu.add_command(label="update...", command=lambda: CreateWindow(some_arguments, go_here))`

This is effectively equivalent to:

```
def f():
     CreateWindow(some_arguments, go_here)

filemenu.add_command(label="update...", command=f)
```

... But much shorter.